# Labels in file_sd_config - promtail

Tags: promtail

How to assing label form path for scrape_configs when using file_sd_config?

In file_sd_config file I have paths like this:

```
/opt/app/node01/server1/out.log
/opt/app/node02/server2/out.log
/opt/app/node03/server3/out.log
```

and I would like to have labels for each server in the each path.

For now my config.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: app
    file_sd_config:
      - files:
        - /home/user/config.yml
    relabel_config:
      - source_labels: [job]
        target_label: job
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: nodename
      - source_labels: [nodename]
        target_label: __path__
```